# Why isn't the php used inside javascript not rendering dropdown values. I am getting a blank dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to get a dropdown list with options being rendered from the php syntax written inside the JavaScript.
But it doesn't seem to give me the expected output. I am getting a blank dropdown.

---

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

function func() {
    var string = "";
    var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if (a === "SE-IT-A" || a === "SE-IT-B") { <? php foreach($arr1 as $x = > $x_value) { ?>
                string = string + "<option>" + <? php echo $arr1[$x]; ?> +"</option>";
            document.write(string); <? php
        } ?>
    }
    string = "Select Subject: <select required name='second'>" + string + "</select>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = string;
}  

</script>
<div id="output"></div><br>
</html>
```

Comment: `func()` is not  a self-invoking function, you have to call it somewhere. And please, provide the full code, including the PHP.

Comment: As Periplo mentioned, your function is never being invoked. Your page also misses the element id="input" which should have an event handler to call func() and thirdly PHP is executed on the server side, Javascript on the client side, so whenever func() is invoked, the server side is already done executing. So you can't do it like that. You either have to use an XMLHttpRequest or you let PHP write all your available OPTIONs into Javascript arrays beforehand.